# How do I move PhpStorm tool windows to the right hand side?

Tags: phpstorm

A co-worker has PhpStorm configured to have the Project tool window on the left-hand side and the Structure tool window on the right-hand side (to the right of the editor). But he can't remember how he configured it that way, and I can't figure out how. I found a reference to the "right side" in the PhpStorm documentation ([see "Side by side layout on the left/right"](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/appearance.html#d408660e396)), but I can't find any instructions for moving a tool window to the right side.

**Update:** I'm using PhpStorm 7.1 on Mac OS X.

Regarding [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)'s comment: the tool window is not draggable. And I've tried different modes (like Pinned Mode and Docked Mode), but it remains undraggable in the combinations of modes I've tried.

Comment: You mean like "grab toolwindow (by clicking and holding left mouse button) and move it from left side to the right side of the IDE screen" ??

Comment: If you're going to vote the question down, at least do me the courtesy of commenting on why. I don't see why this isn't a legitimate question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hey Thats easy one just try to drag the part which is marked. Not the window [image]

It is working on windows 7/ PHPStorm 7.1
**[Update]**
This wont work if you don't turn on tool buttons

Comment: I had to turn on Tool Buttons first (View->Tool Buttons). But (yay!) once I did, I could drag the Structure tool button to the right. If you add turning on Tool Buttons to your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DarylSpitzer That is a new knowledge for me too. May be some kinda bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. I think by design, they made the Tool Buttons draggable instead of the Windows themselves. I don't recall if that was off by default (which would be unfortunate) or if I turned it off.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the tool window you need from the main menu or a short-cut:
   [image: PhpStorm - View > Tool Windows > Structure (Alt+7)]
2. Right click on the appropriate tool window title (e.g. `Structure PHP`):
   [image: PhpStorm - Structure Window Right-click]
3. From the pop-up menu, select `Move to`, then select `Right` or whatever you need:
   [image: PhpStorm - Structure Window Right-click > Move to > Right]